# MERN Pagination & Sorting

Tags: sorting, pagination, filtering, mern

hopefully, you guys will be able to help me out please.

I can't get the pagination to work properly. It always counts the total documents and ignores the filter data. For example, there are 24 total documents, but when filters by a particular item it returns one, but still returns the total amount of pages (which is 3 as I have pageSize set to 9).

Please find my code below:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const pageSize = 9;
    const page = Number(req.query.page) || 1;

    let query;
    const queryObject = { ...req.query };
    const excludeFields = ['page', 'sort', 'limit', 'fields'];
    excludeFields.forEach((el) => delete queryObject[el]);

    let queryString = JSON.stringify(queryObject);
    queryString = queryString.replace(
      /\b(gte|gt|lte|lt)\b/g,
      (match) => `$${match}`
    );

    query = Vehicle.find(JSON.parse(queryString));
    if (req.query.sort) {
      const sortBy = req.query.sort.split(',').join(' ');
      query = query.sort(sortBy);
    } else {
      query = query.sort('-createdAt');
    }

    const count = await Vehicle.countDocuments();
    const vehicles = await Vehicle.find(JSON.parse(queryString))
      .limit(pageSize)
      .skip(pageSize * (page - 1));

    if (!vehicles) {
      return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: [] });
    }

    res
      .status(200)
      .json({ vehicles, page, totalPages: Math.ceil(count / pageSize) });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```

How would you go about adding functioning sorting into this also please, for some reason sorting doesn't work at all for me?

Thanks very much, G.

Answer (score 0):

1. To get the count to include the filtered data you need to add the query parameter in the countDocuments:

```js
 const count = await Vehicle.countDocuments(JSON.parse(queryString));
```

2. To add sorting functionality you can append .sort() onto the end of you find query:

```js
const vehicles = await Vehicle.find(JSON.parse(queryString))
      .limit(pageSize)
      .skip(pageSize * (page - 1))
      .sort(<your sort query>)
```

https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/sorting-with-mongoose-and-mongodb/122573